# Should I cache System.getProperty("line.separator")?

Tags: java, caching, optimization

Consider such method:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (final Room room : map)
    {
        sb.append(room.toString());
        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator")); // THIS IS IMPORTANT
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

`System.getProperty("line.separator")` can be called many times.

Should I cache this value with `public final static String lineSeperator = System.getProperty("line.separator")`
and later use only `lineSeperator`?

Or `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is as fast as using a static field?

Comment: I think System.getProperty should lookup for the specified key each time you call it. I don't know if the compiler make any optimization about. Let's see what people suggest.

Comment: Are you using Java 7 or an older version?

Comment: @chrylis I'm using 6, I'm thinking about starting with 7 (so far I don't see strong reasons to upgrade...). Is there any difference between 6 and 7 with this `getProperty()`?

Comment: Yes, 7 promoted this specific issue to `System.lineSeparator()`. Probably not worth upgrading for, but it's a simpler answer if you're already using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your question as presenting a false dichotomy. I would neither call `getProperty` every time, nor declare a static field for it. I'd simply extract it to a local variable in `toString`.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    final String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
    for (final Room room : map) sb.append(room.toString()).append(newline);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

BTW I have benchmarked the call. The code:

```
public class GetProperty
{
  static char[] ary = new char[1];
  @GenerateMicroBenchmark public void everyTime() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) ary[0] = System.getProperty("line.separator").charAt(0);
  }
  @GenerateMicroBenchmark public void cache() {
    final char c = System.getProperty("line.separator").charAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) ary[0] = (char)(c | ary[0]);
  }
}
```

The results:

```
Benchmark                     Mode Thr    Cnt  Sec         Mean   Mean error    Units
GetProperty.cache            thrpt   1      3    5       10.318        0.223 ops/msec
GetProperty.everyTime        thrpt   1      3    5        0.055        0.000 ops/msec
```

The cached approach is more than two orders of magnitude faster.

Do note that the overall impact of `getProperty` call against all that string building is very, very unlikely to be noticeable.

Comment: not a good answer, if caching is faster you should cache it to static, what if you call `toString` multiple times?

Comment: The system property can change between calls. Especially, the user might set it just once, but after this class has already been initialized. On the other hand, static caching will win over one access per `toString` call only if the number of items in the map is very small. You can't claim this is "not a good answer" by mentioning an alternative which just has different tradeoffs than this one.

Comment: why would System.getProperty("line.separator") change so often? If the line separator was changing inbween calls, then surely any toStringiness would be impossible to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to fear that the line separator will change while your code is running, so I see no reason against caching it.

Caching a value is certainly faster than executing a call over and over, but the difference will probably be negligible.

Comment: Depends on whether the call is inlined during hotspot optimization :)

Comment: Oh right, good point. But I personally don't like relying on such features - isn't it better to have code that *already* looks efficient?

Comment: I completely agree!  Too often fellow developers wave away honest inefficiency using the excuse that it will be fixed during runtime. Just bringing up a point.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison The inlining of the call will have absolutely no impact since the majority of time is spent *within* the `getProperty` method. If you meant that the JIT might inline the *value* returned from the method, I'd say that is highly unlikely, and my benchmark confirms that for OpenJDK 7.

Comment: The latter is what I meant. And yes I saw your benchmark, nice work. I must be mistaken.

Comment: @MightyPork I disagree, it is more important that your code looks readable and maintainable than that it looks optimized (which usually means the code is unreadable and unmaintainable). JIT optimizations is what allows us to write efficient and well written OO code (e.g always accessing all your instance variables with getters instead of refering to them directly, knowing the get call will be inline anyway). If we have a feature that allows us to have well readable, maintainable AND optimized code, why not make use of it?

Answer (score 3):

If you have become aware of a performance problem that you know relates to this, yes.

If you haven't, then no, the lookup is unlikely to have enough overhead to matter.

This would fall under either or both of the general categories "micro-optimization" and "premature optimization." :-)

---

But if you're worried about efficiency, you probably have a **much** bigger opportunity in that your `toString` method is regenerating the string every time. If `toString` will be called a lot, rather than caching the line terminator, cache the generated string, and clear that whenever your map of rooms changes. E.g.:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    if (cachedString == null)
    {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        for (final Room room : map)
        {
            sb.append(room.toString());
            sb.append(ls);
        }
        cachedString = sb.toString();
    }
    return cachedString;
}
```

...and when your map changes, do

```
cachedString = null;
```

That's a **lot** more bang for the buck (the buck being the overhead of an extra field). Granted it's per-instance rather than per-class, so (reference earlier comment about efficiency) only do it if you have a good reason to.

Comment: Premature optimisation can be counter-productive when it leads to "bad" code. In this case the code will be faster and as readable (if not more) so I don't think it falls in that category...

Comment: @assylias: First, let me say: There are few people who are worse about premature optimization than I am. :-) But PO isn't (only) about creating bad code. It's about spending time, energy, and memory optimizing things that don't need optimization, when you *could* be using that time, energy, and memory optimizing things that *do* need optimization or adding to functionality.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have nothing to oppose that, but in this particular case I'd extract the local variable with performance not even entering my mind.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: No issue with using a local in a function. The OP talks about using a `static`, though, see comments to Alex MDC.

Comment: Yes, I've just added that to my answer. OP simply presents a false dichotomy: call every time or make a static field.

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Since it's so easy to do, why not? *At the very least* the implementation of `System.getProperty()` will have to do a hash table lookup (even if cached internally) to find the property you are requesting, then the virtual method `getString()` will be called on the resulting Object. None of these are very expensive but will need to be called multiple times. Not to mention many `String` temporaries will be created and need GCing after.

If you move this out to the top of your loop and reuse the same value, you avoid all of these problems. So why not?

Comment: *"Since it's so easy to do, why not?"* Because if it doesn't matter, creating additional static fields is a bad idea. Should every class that uses any system property that doesn't change keep its own copy of it? And other things that don't change? When there's no clear performance gain? No. That just leads to cluttering up memory with redundant information.

Comment: I agree, and I actually meant calculating it once, inside the function, before entering the loop. I didn't notice the OP was using a suggesting using a static value.

Comment: @ alex: Ah, yes, that's different. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the system property is guaranteed to remain constant during the application it can be cached but in general you will loose the feature of the property which is changing the behavior when you change it.

For instance a text generator could use the property to generate text for windows or for linux and allow the property to be changed dynamically in the application, why not ?

In general, catching a property implies making useless the function setProperty.