# Line separator for Windows in java

Tags: java, string, file, newline

I would like to save some words into *.txt file. But there is one condition: each word must be on new line. So I wrote this:

```
String content ="";
String nl = System.lineSeparator();
content += "my" + nl + "some" + nl + "random" + nl + "words";
```

But this code not working - all words are in the same line.

So i tried with special characters - `\r\n` :

```
String content ="";
content += "my" + "\r\n" + "some" + "\r\n" + "random" + "\r\n" + "words";
```

Still didn't works - in file all words are in same line:

> mysomerandomwords

In addition to this: my string `content` is save to file by:

```
<a href="data:text/txt;charset=utf-8,<%=content%>" download="results.txt"><button class="button">Download</button></a>
```

What kind of separator should I use to put words in another lines?

(I'm using Netbeans 8.0. File is opens in windows notepad).

Comment: Try URL Encoding the `content`.

Comment: avoid using the windows-notepad. if you don't want to use something like Notepad++, try windows wordpad, at least it displays the line seperators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `base64` in `data` URI scheme:

```
<a href="data:text/txt;charset=utf-8;base64,<%=base64_content%>" download="results.txt"><button class="button">Download</button></a>
```

In your Java code do:

```
String content ="";
String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
content += "my" + nl + "some" + nl + "random" + nl + "words";
content = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(content.getBytes("utf-8"));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bDRAq

Comment: @1_bug It doesn't if done the right way: http://jsfiddle.net/bDRAq/ (sorry I missed base64, updated)

Answer (score 2):

Try with `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Read it here about [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) with complete list of System properties.

The System class maintains a Properties object that describes the configuration of the current working environment.

> "line.separator"   -  Sequence used by operating system to **separate lines in text files**

---

What [System.lineSeparator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29) states?

> Returns the system-dependent line separator string. It always returns the same value - the initial value of the system property line.separator.
>
> On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it returns "\r\n".

---

#### Why use `System.getProperty()`?

"line.separator" property can be changed by passing arguments as shown below

```
java -Dline.separator=
```

Have a look at [Should I cache System.getProperty(“line.separator”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045391/should-i-cache-system-getpropertyline-separator)

Comment: why? is it different than  System.lineSeparator() ?

Comment: How is this different from `System.lineSeparator()` except the fact that `System.lineSeparator()` reads `line.separator` system property only once?

Comment: @pingw33n Look what [Oracle Java Tutorial on System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) states about this property.

Comment: @Braj: nothing's changed. Still all words are in the same line.

Comment: Why it's not working for you? Is this your actual code? Please share a complete code to reproduce it.

Comment: @Braj And what should I find there? Your answer is useless because both things are basically the same.

Comment: @pingw33n Something is wrong with the OP's code. If OP is ready to share the code then I'll update my post.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends how you write down the content. If you write it to a file on the filesystem, it will most likely end up correctly. But you are not saving it to a file with your program, but you let the browser do that by including a link in a html file. When including characters in HTML, you need to encode them with the [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class.

Since it looks to me that you are working within an WebContainer, since you JSP structures, you could also implement a Servlet that returns the requested data.

Comment: I tried URLEncoder and it's working, but if I had strings like "A=2", "B=5" etc. it returns "A+2", "B+5".